# What is the difference in OpenSSH 7.6 vs 7.6p1

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have two Linux machines from which I make ssh connections to different hosts however I find that the client versions on these two Linux machines are `OpenSSH_7.6` and `OpenSSH_7.6p1`. I tried to look up the differences between these two versions at https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html but it seems they are same version.
I would like to understand what is the difference in these two versions if any and why such nomenclature strategy.

Answer (score 0):

not very difference but in 7.7p1 its change

you can check this diff in https://fossies.org/diffs/openssh/7.6p1_vs_7.7p1/

or check all change log commit in here https://fossies.org/diffs/openssh/7.6p1_vs_7.7p1/ChangeLog-diff.html

Comment: the question is about `OpenSSH 7.6` vs `7.6p1` where as the  above link is comparing 7.6p1 vs 7.7p1.

Comment: @KrishnaOza for 7.6 vs 7.6p1 version not difference in main site or by commit

Comment: if there is no difference then still I would like to understand why such naming scheme exists

Comment: @KrishnaOza i check code by diff check but i don't find any .. 
but between 7.6 to 7.7 is change .

and all version have same p1 version i think it's like a duplicate with some difference in structure .

Answer (score 0):

As found on https://www.openssh.com/portable.html

`The portable OpenSSH follows development of the official version, but releases are not synchronized. Portable releases are marked with a 'p' (e.g. 4.0p1). The official OpenBSD source will never use the 'p' suffix, but will instead increment the version number when they hit 'stable spots' in their development.`